# embed crystal-lang version in an application

Tags: crystal-lang

I wanted to embed the Crystal version as well as the app version in my code. I came up with this:

```
  macro crystal_version
    {{ `crystal env`.stringify.split("\n")[2] }}.split("=")[1].gsub("\"", "")
  end
```

This seems a bit clumsy to me - all the array massaging and substitution. I'm also depending on the info I need being in the same place at a later date. Is there something within the language that I can use to accomplish the same thing?

Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`Crystal::VERSION`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/Crystal.html#VERSION) constant.

Comment: Just follow the link?